# Can somebody please tell me who this figure is and where it is from?

Tags: merchandise

I got a set of 4 anime figures together. The first 3 all came in a box but the fourth one has no box and no stand. No matter what I search, I can't seem to find her.

She has purple eyes and a red shield with 2 overlapping wings on the insignia on her armband.

[image: figure]

Answer (score 8):

That would be [Leila Malcal](http://codegeass.wikia.com/wiki/Leila_Malcal) from *Code Geass: Akito of the Exiled*

[image: Leila Macal]

Aside from her attire which as you can see above matches what give it away is her hairstyle which has two egg shaped buns that are usually held up with gold coloured braces